# It is possible to use VLP-16-lite on ROS indigo & kinetic?

Tags: ros-kinetic, ros-indigo, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm planning to buy VLP-16 or VLP-16-lite. So I want to know that there is a driver for VLP-16 & VLP-16-lite on ROS.

I found that I can get the driver for VLP-16 on indigo & kinetic from [here](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne).

And I found that the [site](https://autonomoustuff.com/product/velodyne-puck-lite/) which says there is the driver for VLP-16-lite(Puck lite). But I'm wondering if the site says truth or not...

So if someone know there is a driver for VLP-16-lite, could you inform me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259259/it-is-possible-to-use-vlp-16-lite-on-ros-indigo-&-kinetic?/) by [graziegrazie](https://answers.ros.org/users/28176/graziegrazie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2017-04-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Augusto Luis Ballardini](https://answers.ros.org/users/234/augusto-luis-ballardini/) on 2017-04-15**:
Hi, I have a VLP-16 in my university lab and I'm currently using the lidar with the standard velodyne_driver ros package (and the calibration yaml file). Since the only difference should be the weight, I suppose it's going to work with the lite version too..

**Comment by [graziegrazie](https://answers.ros.org/users/28176/graziegrazie/) on 2017-04-24**:
I think so, but I want the evidence. VLP-16 and VLP-16-LITE is very expensive. And I want to skip to develop driver for the LITE on ROS. That is why I want to confirm if there is a drive for the LITE or not.

**Comment by [amburkoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/18441/amburkoff/) on 2018-07-20**:
Have you checked it? Does VLP-16 work in ROS kinetic?

**Comment by [graziegrazie](https://answers.ros.org/users/28176/graziegrazie/) on 2018-07-20**:
Yes, I checked. VLP-16 works well in ROS Kinetic.

**Comment by [amburkoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/18441/amburkoff/) on 2018-07-20**:
Does VLP-16-LITE work in ROS kinetic? Or does the driver come from the regular version?

**Comment by [graziegrazie](https://answers.ros.org/users/28176/graziegrazie/) on 2018-07-25**:
I have not tried VLP-16 LITE on any distribution.
Now I cannot confirm which driver I used. But maybe you can use [this](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The VLP-16 has been tested on Indigo and Kinetic with velodyne_driver version 1.3.0, which must currently be built from source on both those repositories.

I have no reports of testing with the VLP-16-lite. If you try it, please report back whether it works or not, or edit [the wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne) to add the additional model.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2017-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [graziegrazie](https://answers.ros.org/users/28176/graziegrazie/) on 2017-04-24**:
OK. If I test the LITE with velodyne_driver, I'll update the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne).